# How to make Flow understand a component will receive required props by cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a component that will set a `required` property to all its `children`, but Flow doesn't seem to understand it.

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

type BarProps = { required: 'defined' };
const Bar = ({ required }: BarProps) => <span />

type FooProps = { children: Array<React.Element<any>> };
const Foo = ({ children }: FooProps) =>
    React.Children.map(
      children,
      child => React.cloneElement(child, { required: 'defined' })
    );

<Foo children={[<Bar />]} />
```

Here's the [Flow repro](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciiOAnukqgAQkSwAFRujIBeUAG9Q7AI4BXZOwAmALlZbKkZADtKWlqAC+PGrGMk8YrKHkAKJao3arep1NgyAJQuAHygADwk6ETGoMAhvAJCoABisLD+Mi6KoDQAFsjQWuzGegCCWFhE-OFUtDgAdACi0JSolMY44TH8IWHWiLb2eGmw2e65BUUlPqnpmSTBsgkAkHV0DQDCU8UdDahE6K6IoKdn+YW7xgA0J2enF0WhFByNNHCmLW0dOK6PWtccp5NGY9CwDEZTOYrIE7qdAjxEOFRpNLiVZAoANrhJxxEIAXUseMQQA), the error it returns is:

```
14: <Foo children={[<Bar />]} />
                     ^ Cannot create `Bar` element because property `required` is missing in props [1] but exists in `BarProps` [2].
References:
14: <Foo children={[<Bar />]} />
                    ^ [1]
5: const Bar = ({ required }: BarProps) => <span />
                              ^ [2]
```

I know the design isn't the best and I should have used a render-prop probably, but this is some old code I'm trying to fix and I can't change the API that easily.

How can I make Flow understand this code?

Comment: Change `type BarProps = { required: 'defined' };` to `type BarProps = { required?: 'defined' };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to pass a React element (e.g. `<Bar />`) instead of the React component (e.g. `Bar`), then you have instantiated the component without the required props, so Flow is correctly reporting an error. You would need to change the interface to accept a `React.Component` instead of a `React.Element` to get what you want.